# VBA Code too slow - Matching the value of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets and they are put into TabName1 and TabName2. I am trying to take the value from a column and match it with all the values in the column and if the value is not found then I am deleting that row from sheet2

This is the Code,

```
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    CombinedKeyVal = Sheets(TabName2).Range(CombinedKeyColLet & i).Value
    Present = Application.Match(CombinedKeyVal, Sheets(TabName1).Columns(CombinedKeyCol), 0)
    If IsError(Present) Then
        Sheets(TabName2).Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If

Next
```

Yes , the lastrow is defined as,

```
lastrow = Sheets(TabName1).Cells(Rows.Count, BuColm).End(xlUp).Row
```

It works. But it is too slow. My lastrow is around 5000. So, Any Idea or Suggestion to increase the Speed of the Process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` outside of your loop within your sub.

Comment: Yes that is already there inside the Sub.

Comment: ^ and don't use select, just `Sheets(TabName2).Rows(i).Delete`

Comment: How did you define `lastRow`? (just make sure it's not going from the last possible row, and you've set it correctly to be the last data row).

Comment: Do not use `Select`, it slows down the macro

Comment: Updated the lastrow along with the question. let me try without the select option.

Comment: I tried to use delete without using select as suggested. But even that is running for more than 2 minutes.

Comment: Did you disable calculation & screenupdating? those are hogs when it comes to runtime.

Comment: I didn't disable calculation. But I did disable screenupdating.

Comment: Every time you delete a row, the worksheet needs to recalculate. Disable both, and re-enable at the end of the procedure.

Comment: @DavidZemens I haven't tried the 'specialcells' method before and therefore try and going to stick to the same method for time being. How do you use recalculate? before calculating the lastrow or after calculating the lastrow?

Comment: Disregard comment on SpecialCells, I don't think that works in this case. My mistake.

Comment: You want to disable Calculation at the *beginning* of the procedure, and re-enable it at the *end* of the procedure.  See the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/9798/excel-vba-optimization#t=201707071611033711192) for some suggestions to do this.

Comment: On Debugging, I just found out that deletion is too slow ! Any suggestions or a quicker way to delete than what has been said.

Comment: Assuming the code works as intended (just too slow), if you include the whole procedure (or better, the whole module!) in a post on [codereview.se], you'll get feedback on **all** aspects of the code, including performance, but also best practices, readability and maintainability.

Comment: `Union` the ranges you want to delete, and then make *one* deletion operation. That would be equivalent to Ctrl+Click selecting the rows you want to delete, and then deleting them all at once.

Comment: @Mat's Mug how would union in this case ?

Comment: See [this CR answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122938/23788)

Comment: CR Answer ? I didn't get that

Comment: CR = [codereview.se]. It's a link, just click it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, note also the use of `Worksheet` object variables, while this is probably negligible in performance, it is something of a best practice according to DRY: assign the object once, and then just use the object rather than repeatedly calling on `Sheets("some sheet name")`.

```
Dim sh2 as Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set sh2 = Sheets(TabName2)
Set sh1 = Sheets(TabName1)

''' more code goes here when you calculate lastrow, etc.

For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    CombinedKeyVal = sh2.Range(CombinedKeyColLet & i).Value
    Present = Application.Match(CombinedKeyVal, sh1.Columns(CombinedKeyCol), 0)
    If IsError(Present) Then
        sh2.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 
    End If
Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Marking it as answer as no better answer was provided for this question.